# Open flow with using a slider in ipad

Tags: ipad, slider, quartz-graphics, coverflow

I need a cover flow in the ipad.I have implemented the cover flow application using http://apparentlogic.com/openflow. But it uses mouse to flick the images. I need the same also using a slider. How can i do it???

Comment: No because this is not a "send me the code" site.